# SQL double colon meaning

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

// A - calculate the sum of payments for one day 2021-01-02

```
SELECT SUM(PAYMENT) AS TOT_PAYMENTS
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE (PAY_DATE::timestamp)::date = '2021-01-02'
```

The datatype of PAY_DATE is TIMESTAMP, so i found a way in another question to convert it to DATETIME while filtering and it seems to be working. My question is where can i find the documentation for this type of method? I could only find references to CAST and PARSE methods, can somebody explain this syntax to me?

Comment: Well, those are [type casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) - one useless cast from timestamp to timestamp and then another one from timestamp to date

Comment: Ok i get it now, it's just the postgre sintax of CAST. I also modified it as just WHERE PAY_DATE::date = '2021-01-02' and it still works perfectly :)

Comment: On a side note, that query has to strip time component for every row in the table and probably cannot benefit from indexes. We'd have to see the execution plan, but it's possible that something like `WHERE PAY_DATE >= '2021-01-02'
AND PAY_DATE < '2021-01-03'` provides better performance.

Comment: Performance are not important in my case, but thank You, i'll keep in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Hope you are doing well!

I know that Amazon Redshift has such syntaxes for the data types converting, e.g. you can find it in the documentation (see the first section CAST):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html

```
expression :: type
```

`expression` - an expression that evaluates to one or more values, such as a column name or a literal. Converting null values returns nulls. The expression cannot contain blank or empty strings.

`type` - one of the supported data types.

`return type` - the data type specified by the type argument.